# OpenXML Images added with AddImagePart not showing up in document.xml.rels

Tags: xml, image, openxml, docx

I'm trying to add an image to an existing Word 2010 document using OpenXML SDK 2.5. But when I add the image the image does not get embedded.  When I open the document, the image shows the placeholder with a red cross (as if the image cannot be found).
I'm using the following code:

```
string mimetype = String.Empty;
// :
//Find mime type of the image here
// :
imagePart = wpd.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(mimetype);

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    image = new Bitmap(stream);
    cy = Convert.ToUInt32(image.PhysicalDimension.Height);
    cx = Convert.ToUInt32(image.PhysicalDimension.Width);
    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
    stream.Close();
 }
 Paragraph para = FindParagraphInAppendix(....); //Find the paragraph to add
 if (para != null)
    AddImageToParagraph(para, wpd.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart),txt, filename,cx,cy);
 else
      wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(GetImageWithPara(wpd.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), filename, cx, cy));
wpd.Package.CreateRelationship(imagePart.Uri, System.IO.Packaging.TargetMode.External,wpd.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
```

In the code for AddImageToParagraph I'm adding the image as follows:

```
Pic.BlipFill blipFill1 = new Pic.BlipFill();
A.Blip blip1 = new A.Blip() { Embed = relationshipid,
                             CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print };
A.BlipExtensionList blipExtensionList1 = new A.BlipExtensionList();
```

When I open the file generated using Winzip, the document.xml.rels file does not contain a relationship ID associated with the embedded image.

When I open the using OpenXML Productivity tool and validate the XML I get the error : "The relationship 'R75a8cc179...' referenced by attribute 'hxxp://schemas.openxmlformats..../relationships:embed' does not exist 
Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you maybe send the generated docx to see wha'ts exactly the issue ?

Comment: Can't really upload the document.  But what strikes as odd is imagePart.AddImagePart is not creating a `<Relationship>` tag in the resulting document.xml.rels.  All examples I'm seeing seem to do exactly what I'm doing...

Comment: Additional information: wpd.GetReferenceRelationship(wpd.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart)) throws a System.Generic.Collections.KeyNotFoundException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally figured this out
The issue was after the MainDocumentPart was edited I was only calling `wordProcessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Save()`.  I was not calling the `Close()` method.  Due to this the ImagePart relationship was not being committed into the package.  I think the `Close()` method causes the relationship to be "written" to `word\_rels\document.xml.rels` section of the docx package!

Comment: Thanks man, you just saved my life... or at least a big portion of it :)

Comment: MainDocumentPart does not have a save method, neither a close method. I think you used the document class?